# Is it necessary to use eval in this case?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In book *Metaprogramming Ruby*:164 written by Paolo Perrotta，there is an example using `eval`.

```
map = { "update" => "deploy:update" ,
        "restart" => "deploy:restart" ,
        "cleanup" => "deploy:cleanup" ,
# ...
}
map.each do |old, new|
  # ...
  eval "task(#{old.inspect}) do
    warn \"[DEPRECATED] `#{old}' is deprecated. Use `#{new}' instead.\"
    find_and_execute_task(#{new.inspect})
  end"
end
```

Is this use of `eval` necessary? I can write a code like the following:

```
map = { "update" => "deploy:update" ,
        "restart" => "deploy:restart" ,
        "cleanup" => "deploy:cleanup" ,
        # ...
        }
map.each do |old, new|
    task(old.inspect) do
        warn \"[DEPRECATED] `#{old}' is deprecated. Use `#{new}' instead.\"
        find_and_execute_task(new.inspect)
    end
end
```

I think it's unnecessary to use `eval` this way. Is that just a programming style trying to let everything to use string substitution?

Comment: If you can evade `eval`, do it. Here it seems to be not necessary, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` is not necessary, but your code will not work either. It is not valid Ruby code. It should be

```
map.each do |old, new|
  task(old) do
    warn "[DEPRECATED] `#{old}' is deprecated. Use `#{new}' instead."
    find_and_execute_task(new)
  end
end
```